# Getting substrings (strings with "") with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

I have a main string like this:

```
const mainString: string = `
let myStr: string = "Hello world";
function x() { }
let otherVar: number = 4;
let otherString: string = "Other string value";
// something else INSIDE the main string
`;
```

Now I need to format this main string, but substrings cause unwanted stuff, so I need to get them.

The regex I used until now was: `/"([^"]*)"/g`.
With it I would get e.g. `['"Hello world"', '"Other string value"']` (in the mainString context from above).

But having a `"\""` inside one of these substring, would throw off my regex and give me the part from the beginning until the `\"` and then, if some other substring was used anywhere else, give me the real end of the substring `"` (falsly as a start symbol) until the start of the next substring...

One important thing: I have absolutly **no control** what so ever about anything before and beyont the `"substring value"`.

What would be the correct regex for my usecase?

Comment: `['"Hello world"', .....` sorry but why the `'"` and `"'` ??

Comment: Also, you said you don't have control of the other stuff around... so could you explain how should this string be treated `function x(option = "Default") {` ??

Comment: because I still need the `"` itself in the substring

Comment: `function x(option = "Default") {` would also have a substring so it would remove it, every single thing inside `""` have to be removed, no matter where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
"((\\"|[^"])*?)"
```

`\\"` - mean look for `\"`

`|` - or

`*?` - for no greedy

see: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FOaZYK/1/)